# Export TeeChart(.Net) as PDF: Unicode characters not rendered correctly in exported PDF

Tags: .net, teechart

I am using TeeChart for .Net, version 4.1.2015.8062; in my forms application developed on .Net 4.0 in VS2010. I am exporting TeeChart as PDF. When I open the PDF, it does not show the axis title correctly. My axis title is '(δ): μ_t−μ_c' with unicode characters in it.

Does anyone has faced this kind of problem earlier, and have found any workaround for it?
Any help is really appreciable.

Thank you,

Jaqen

Comment: Does it happen with a blank chart? Otherwise, could you please arrange a [simple example project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here?

Comment: Not with blank chart. it happens for chart with multiple line series having legends. Legends are having check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as the ticket [#20](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20), which equivalent in VCL is [#313](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=313).

Try printing the chart using a virtual pdf printer. It seems to work fine for me here.